# How to filter a list for multiple condition using java 8 stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This Code works fine in java 7.
Iteration in java 8 is successful but I am stacked while if else decision making.
I have one list in which i have integer as well as double value. How can i parse this and set to in model class?

```
AverageRatingModel avgRatingModel = new AverageRatingModel();
for(Property p:propertylist){
    if(p.getName().equals("averagevote")){
        avgRatingModel.setAvgRating(Double.parseDouble(p.getValue()));
    }
    if(p.getName().equals("nbvotes")){
        avgRatingModel.setNoOfVotes(Integer.parseInt(p.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is strange: you are setting values (`setAvgRating` or `setNoOfVotes`) on the same object `avgRatingModel` again and again. Is that normal?

Comment: Do you mean you want to automatically bind a property `prop` in `propertylist` to the `prop` member of your `AverageRatingModel` class ?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two streams but it would be horrible. It would must better to have a data structure which is designed for Properties.

```
properties.ifPresentDouble("averagevote", avgRatingModel::setAvgRating);
properties.ifPresentInt("nbvotes", avgRatingModel::setNoOfVotes);
```

You code will be much cleaner if you have useful data structure for your properteis.